# Starting an application as a service in RedHat 6 is not using expected Java system properties

Tags: java, unix, service, redhat, jbossfuse

I'm trying to start my application as a service on RedHat 6 using `service myapplication start`.
The process seems to use Java 1.6 parameters while JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to Java 1.7, But, if I'm starting the same as `/etc/init.d/myapplication start`, it is using the expected Java 1.7.

Comment: Is it set `JAVA_HOME` in `init` script?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set in `/etc/profile.d/`. Looks like the environment variables are not available to the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your SYSV init file (`/etc/init.d/myapplication`) and set there `JAVA_HOME`.